# Spring data neo4j: findAll return null , when result pass to another list

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Problem is: I have Spring data neo4j jar, which is have Spring service, I am getting list of result , but then I pass result to front end it is null.
Data is created, in back end side result is not null.

```
 @Autowired
    private Neo4jTemplate template;
    @Autowired
    private ArticleRepository articleRepository;
    @Autowired
    private GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService;
    @Autowired
    private Neo4jOperations neo4jOperations;


    @Transactional
    public List<Article> getAllArticleList() {
        List<Article> allList = new ArrayList<Article>();
        Iterable<Article> items = template.findAll(Article.class);
        if (items != null) {
            for (Article u : items) {
                // Article item = neo4jOperations.convert(u, Article.class);
                System.out.println("Article " + u.getId());
                System.out.println("Article 2 " + u.getArticleName());
                allList.add(u);
            }
        }
        return allList;
    }
```

Here result is printed, I am adding it to allList after print.

Second part,

this is a method from JSF bean, form this bean also I made test data,
size is printing, but data is null.

```
public List<Article> getAllArticles() {
        List<Article> allList = new ArrayList<Article>();
         System.out.println("##########Article list size######### " + cognitiveService.getAllArticleList().size());
           for (Article cc : springBean.getAllArticleList()) {
                System.out.println("Article id is::@@ " + cc.getId());
                System.out.println("Article name:::@@ " + cc.getArticleName());
            }
           try {             
            allList.addAll(springBean.getAllArticleList());            

            for (Article c : allList) {
                System.out.println("Article id is:: " + c.getId());
                System.out.println("Article name::: " + c.getArticleName());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return allList;
    }
```

Spring neo4j configuration

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com"}, excludeFilters = {
    @ComponentScan.Filter(Configuration.class)})
@ImportResource("classpath:META-INF/spring/application-context.xml")
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.PROXY)
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
//@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableMBeanExport
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com")
public class Application extends Neo4jConfiguration {

    public Application() {
        setBasePackage("com");
    }  

    @Bean
    public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
        return new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("C:/neo4j/db/testdata.db");
    }
```

xml

```
<context:annotation-config/>
    <context:spring-configured/>

    <neo4j:config id="graphDatabaseService" storeDirectory="C:/neo4j/db/testdata.db"  base-package="com.neo4jia.domain"/>
<!--                  -->


    <!-- Instructs Spring Data where to look for repository implementations -->
    <neo4j:repositories base-package="com.neo4jia.repository"/>

<!--     We override the default Label based Type Representation strategy by supplying
    our own "typeRepresentationStrategyFactory" which uses the Legacy indexed based
    strategy. From SDN 3.0 onwards, the default type representation strategy
    is Label based, and in 2.3 and previous it was Indexed based. 
    <bean id="typeRepresentationStrategyFactory" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="graphDatabase"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="Indexed"/>
    </bean>-->

    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"/>
```

I tried change form List to Iterable..... result the same, data is not passed.

```
  <neo4j.version>2.1.5</neo4j.version>
        <neo4j.springdata.version>3.2.1.RELEASE</neo4j.springdata.version>
 <spring.version>4.0.7.RELEASE</spring.version>
```

Comment: What exactly is null? Can you provide the output?

Comment: seems problem from repository naming:(

Comment: Can you download and see the project , here is a link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B45Md1_c5-gGRDZYWklyU2lReFk/view?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

All problems coming from repository naming.

I change repository name to UserRelationRepository , Spring service name to
UserRelationService .
Previous time I did similar, this time I change repository names :((

It solved with old version for Spring data neo4j, but with new still exist.
I am sharing a link with configured project, can anyone download and run and find what is the problem? this is a maven project work under tomcat7/8, from web page you can click and see what node is created but you can not get node name.

link [download the project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B45Md1_c5-gGRDZYWklyU2lReFk/view?pli=1)